# c program not taking input up to 100000

Tags: c

I write a program in c which is supposed to take input from 1 to 100000 but when I run the program I only takes input upto 12773 however I used long long unsigned int for array holding input.

If I gave input less than 12774 the program shows correct behaviour but not more than that input.
The program I made is http://ideone.com/iXM1M0 
I didn't understand this strange behaviour of c.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


unsigned long long int inversion_count(unsigned long long int *arr, unsigned long long int start, unsigned long long int end)
{
    unsigned long long int left_count, right_count, split_count = 0, i, left_arrend, j, no_ele;
    no_ele = end - start;
    unsigned long long int temp_arr[no_ele], k=0;
    if(no_ele == 1)        // this means that only one element is passed
        return 0;
    else
    {
        left_arrend = start + (no_ele/2);
        left_count = inversion_count(arr, start, left_arrend);
        right_count = inversion_count(arr, left_arrend, end);
        i = start;
        j = left_arrend;
        while((i< left_arrend) && (j < end))
        {
            if(arr[i] <= arr[j])
            {
                temp_arr[k] = arr[i];
                i++;
                k++;
            }
            else
            {
                split_count += left_arrend - i;
                temp_arr[k] = arr[j];
                j++;
                k++;
            }
        }
        while(i < left_arrend)
        {
            temp_arr[k] = arr[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }
        while(j < end)
        {
            temp_arr[k] = arr[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }

        for(i=start; i<end; i++)
            arr[i] = temp_arr[i-start];
        return left_count + right_count + split_count;
    }
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long long int num, n = 100000, i, result;
    unsigned long long int sum = 0;
    //    scanf("%lld", &n);
    unsigned long long int arr[n];
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%llu", &arr[i]);
        sum += arr[i];
    }

    result = inversion_count(arr, 0, n);
    //        for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    //            printf("%lld\n", arr[i]);
    printf("%llu\n", result);
    printf("sum = %llu\n", sum);
    printf("n = %llu\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is likely that you're running out of stack space.  In your `inversion_count()` function, you have a VLA:

```
unsigned long long int temp_arr[no_ele], k=0;
```

And I suspect that is using too much space as you are busy recursing.  I'm not sure that there's any advantage to using recursion to count the number of inversions in the array; I'd expect to be using a single linear pass.  Indeed, it isn't clear you need to keep more than the last row and the current row in memory if you only have to count inversions.

Comment: +1. Although this is not the source of OP's current problem, he will face this one as soon as he fixes the previous one :)

Comment: 100000 * 8 = ~800KB, and twice this amount (in main function also) that is ~1.6MB. It is going to be a problem on Windows, but definitely not for *NIX. Your suggestion is still valid nonetheless.

Comment: +1 Also, main()'s arr[n] array is about 6.4 MB. When you add in the recursion, it's very easy to run out of stack space.

Comment: But in any programming contest you can use upto 256MB of space and i think i am not reaching to that range..

Comment: I created a data set and ran it on a Mac; it 'worked' OK, though came up with the answer 2502463994 inversions, which is either grotesquely wrong or means that the inversions you are counting are different from what I expect.  Frankly, I don't understand the `inversion_count()` function.  It's also a good idea to make sure you don't get a premature EOF by checking the result of `scanf()`.

Comment: i got correct answer in linux so i think windows does provide such a large stack..

Comment: I stand to be corrected, but I think the stack on Windows is relatively small — something like 1 MiB. I believe it can be adjusted, but I'm not sure of the details.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with ideone.com, not C. ideone.com has a limit (maximal size) for the input text box, and you're going over those limits with your input.

Either install a compiler on a local  computer and do your work there, or rewrite your program: As your input is only consecutive integers, you can generate them in your program instead of reading them from input.